# constructor pattern matching haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this data type

```
data Struct val =  Empty | Exec1 val
                         | Exec2 val
```

And two dummy functions

```
apply :: Struct -> String
apply (Empty) = "matched Empty"  
apply (exec struct) = "matched Exec1 or Exec2"              

apply' :: Struct val -> String
apply' (Empty)   = "matched Empty"  
apply' (Exec1 _) = "matched Exec1"
apply' (Exec2 _) = "matched Exec2"
```

Second one is working fine, but the first one is causing error: "Parse error in pattern: exec". Can you plase explain why can't I match on constructor this way: 
apply (exec struct) = ... ?

It's causing a lot of boilerplate code when I have multiple constructors in my datatype and must pattern match them all separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why? Because you can only match constructors, and `exec` is kind of a new variable. One reason for this is for example the following:

```
data Struct2 =  Empty | Exec1 String
                      | Exec2 Int

apply :: Struct2 -> String
apply Empty = "matched Empty"  
apply (exec struct) = ??
```

How should anyone know which of `Exec1` and `Exec2` you are matching? You couldn't apply functions here, since the actual type of `struct` couldn't be determined.

If you want to reduce the pattern matching, there are a number of ways, from using `case`, over different `data` implementation (like @Karolis suggested) and helper functions to higher level constructs with more complex types. But that's an endless topic.

Answer (score 23):

In general, if you have several constructors that share data, then it's usually better to refactor the data declaration to something like

```
data Struct val = Empty | NonEmpty StructType val
data StructType = Exec1 | Exec2
```

Now you can pattern match in `apply` like this

```
apply :: Struct -> String
apply (Empty) = "matched Empty"  
apply (NonEmpty exec struct) = "matched Exec1 or Exec2"
```

and you can still also pattern match to a specific Exec-type

```
apply' :: Struct val -> String
apply' (Empty)   = "matched Empty"  
apply' (NonEmpty Exec1 _) = "matched Exec1"
apply' (NonEmpty Exec2 _) = "matched Exec2"
```

Comment: It might even be a good idea to re-use the pre-defined `Maybe` type in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

"exec" is not a type constructor and you can only use those in pattern matching.

What you can do is

```
data Struct val =  Empty | Exec Int val

apply :: Struct -> String
apply (Empty) = "matched Empty"  
apply (Exec _ _) = "matched Exec1 or Exec2"              

apply' :: Struct val -> String
apply' (Empty)   = "matched Empty"  
apply' (Exec 1 _) = "matched Exec1"
apply' (Exec 2 _) = "matched Exec2"
```

Comment: I think you meant “data constructor” rather than “type constructor”.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case you can do the following:

```
apply :: Struct -> String
apply Empty = "matched Empty"  
apply _     = "matched Exec1 or Exec2"
```

This will not scale nicely to more complicated results though.

Answer (score 0):

```
apply Empty = "matched empty"
apply (Exec1 _) = notEmpty
apply (Exec2 _) = notEmpty

notEmpty  = "matched Exec1 or Exec2"
```